# can not display hash in index.html.erb RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I unable to access to data DB for show in index.html.erb , when i create controller and my action set this code :

```
 def index
   @posts = Post.all
 end
```

and in index.html.erb i use this code:

```
<% @posts.each do |lst| %>
    <h2> <%= lst.title %> </h2>
    <h2> <%= lst.content %> </h2>

<% end %>
```

but i have 3 record in DB,when i see view source index.html.erb empty tag 3 records:

```
    <h2>  </h2>
    <h2>  </h2>

    <h2>  </h2>
    <h2>  </h2>

    <h2>  </h2>
    <h2>  </h2>
```

Comment: dose each post has title and content values?

Comment: Yes each post has title and content values

Comment: install this gem: 
https://github.com/pry/pry
then in the view add binding.pry inside the do and you can debug in console

Comment: @Cremz how to debug on console?

Comment: put `<%= h @posts.inspect %>` in there to look at what the posts thing looks like or <%= h lst.inspect %> inside the each loop

Comment: Is this really your code? You didn't by any chance write `<% lst.title %>` instead of `<%= lst.title %>`?

Comment: Your code should work. Check if you have records in your DB - run `rails c` and then `Post.all` - do you get your results?

Comment: find problem when i want to insert to DB  with this command :
irb(main):029:0* post = Post.new(:title => "first post for me", :content => "hello ramin for first post")

you see display Nil why ?

=> #<Post id: nil, title: nil, content: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Comment: here : <Post id: nil, title: nil, content: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
nil save to databse :(

Comment: Most likely you have some validations on that fields so it's not saving them to the DB. [Check your Post model](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

Comment: why set nil ? when i have valid value for my model to save

Comment: When using `.new`, you need to `.save` after, so after `post = Post.new(:title => "first post for me", :content => "hello ramin for first post")` use `post.save`, or use `.create` which does both.

Comment: when i use .save i set value for field title and content , again nil display :(
also .create 

what happen here? i don't undrestand :(

Comment: [please look ](http://s6.picofile.com/file/8238487376/12.PNG)

Comment: found issue i write to model this code  : attr_accessible :title , :content 
now remove this , work it, Thanks ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after installing https://github.com/pry/pry you can write something like:

```
<% @posts.each do |lst| %>
<% binding.pry %>
<h2> <%= lst.title %> </h2>
<h2> <%= lst.content %> </h2>
```

then when you refresh the page, in the terminal where you are running the server you will see that you get a console and you can see what values you have for lst variable

Comment: i install pry but refresh page display error:

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `pry' for #<Binding:0x0000000aee0b38>):
    2: 
    3: 
    4:     <% @posts.each do |lst| %>
    5:         <% binding.pry %>
    6:         <h2> <%= lst.title %> </h2>
    7:         <h2> <%= lst.content %> </h2>
    8:

Comment: restart server. and you can also try what kimmmo said